# cant make gluUnProject() work in Android OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, transformation

I am not getting expected coordinate values from `gluUnProject` function.

I will put some code first. Here is the function which get called on touch event

```
public float[] getWorldSpaceFromMouseCoordinates(float mouseX, float mouseY)
{
    float[] finalCoord = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

    // mouse Y needs to be inverted
    mouseY = (float)_viewport[3] - mouseY;
    float[] mouseZ = new float[1];

    FloatBuffer fb = FloatBuffer.allocate(1);

    GLES20.glReadPixels((int)mouseX, (int)mouseY, 1, 1, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, fb);

    int result = GLU.gluUnProject(mouseX, mouseY, fb.get(0), mViewMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, _viewport, 0, finalCoord, 0);

    float[] temp2 = new float[4];
    Matrix.multiplyMV(temp2, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, finalCoord, 0);
    if(result == GL10.GL_TRUE){
        finalCoord[0] = temp2[0] / temp2[3];
        finalCoord[1] = temp2[1] / temp2[3];
        finalCoord[2] = temp2[2] / temp2[3];

    }

    Log.d("Coordinate:", "" + temp2[0] + "," + temp2[1] + "," + temp2[2]);
    return finalCoord;
}
```

here is setting up matrices

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height)
{
    // Adjust the viewport based on geometry changes,
    // such as screen rotation
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    _viewport = new int[] { 0, 0, width, height };

    float ratio = (float) width / height;

    // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
    // in the onDrawFrame() method
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 2, 7);
}
```

setting up modelview matrix (note that model matrix is just an identity.)

```
    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

So as per my understanding my expectation from this function is that it will give me world coordinates w.r.t origin which is not happening. I am creating a square with following coordinates

```
       _vertices = new float [] { -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, // top left
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // bottom left
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // bottom right
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right
```

however I am getting X values ranging from `(.3, -.3)` Y values ranging in `(.5,-.5)` and Z always `-1.0` for whole viewport. X values in `(0.2,-0.2)` when touching corners of square and Y values in `(0.15, -0.15)`.

Let me know if any more code s required.

Comment: Well, if you want world-space coordinates, I would suggest you stop multiplying the UnProjected coordinates by your view matrix. Right now you are getting eye-space coordinates, which you could have done simply by passing an *identity* matrix to UnProject, instead of your ModelView matrix.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman thanks for reply but still corrdinates are in between `(0.4, -0.4)` for X and y both axis at square edges.

Comment: Actually the range is (.34, -34) to be more precise and why is Z always `-1.0` no matter where i touch ?

Comment: It is possible that you are not reading the depth buffer properly. Window-space Z=0.0 is equal to Z=-1.0 in NDC, though I think that is just a coincidence.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman hi again could you please tell me how can i get access to model view matrix after applying projection and then several rotation translations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what the problem was. `glReadPixels()` with `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` is not supported in OpenGL ES 2.0. That is because I was always getting wrong depth value and hence wrong coordinates. Now I had two choices whether to use an `FBO` and store depth using a shader OR I could do `Ray Picking`(Since I had only one object in scene Si was hoping that `gluUnProject()` will do). I chose former here is my code I hope it will help somebody (Its not not generic and geometry is hard coded)

```
    public float[] getWorldSpaceFromMouseCoordinates(float mouseX, float mouseY)
{
    float[] farCoord = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    float[] nearCoord = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

    // mouse Y needs to be inverted
    //mouseY = (float) _viewport[3] - mouseY;

    // calling glReadPixels() with GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT is not supported in
    // GLES so now i will try to implement ray picking
    int result = GLU.gluUnProject(mouseX, mouseY, 1.0f, mViewMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, _viewport, 0,
            farCoord, 0);

    if (result == GL10.GL_TRUE)
    {
        farCoord[0] = farCoord[0] / farCoord[3];
        farCoord[1] = farCoord[1] / farCoord[3];
        farCoord[2] = farCoord[2] / farCoord[3];
    }

    result = GLU.gluUnProject(mouseX, mouseY, 0.0f, mViewMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, _viewport, 0, nearCoord,
            0);

    if (result == GL10.GL_TRUE)
    {
        nearCoord[0] = nearCoord[0] / nearCoord[3];
        nearCoord[1] = nearCoord[1] / nearCoord[3];
        nearCoord[2] = nearCoord[2] / nearCoord[3];
    }

    float [] dirVector = Vector.normalize(Vector.minus(farCoord, nearCoord));
    float [] rayOrigin =  {0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f};

    Log.d("Far Coordinate:", "" + farCoord[0] + "," + farCoord[1] + "," + farCoord[2]);
    Log.d("Near Coordinate:", "" + nearCoord[0] + "," + nearCoord[1] + "," + nearCoord[2]);
    float [] vertices = { -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, // top left
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // bottom left
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // bottom right
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right

    // calculate normal for square
    float[] v1 = { vertices[3] - vertices[0], vertices[4] - vertices[1], vertices[5] - vertices[2]};
    float[] v2 = { vertices[9] - vertices[0], vertices[10] - vertices[1], vertices[11] - vertices[2]};

    float[] n = Vector.normalize(Vector.crossProduct(v1, v2));

    // now calculate intersection point as per following link
    // http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html

    // our plane passes through origin so findint 't' ll be

    float t = -(Vector.dot(rayOrigin, n) / Vector.dot(dirVector, n));

    // now substitute above t in ray equation gives us intersection point
    float [] intersectionPoint = Vector.addition(rayOrigin, Vector.scalarProduct(t, dirVector));
    Log.d("Ipoint:", "" + intersectionPoint[0] + "," + intersectionPoint[1] + "," + intersectionPoint[2]);
    return intersectionPoint;
}
```